# Is there a way to allow non technical people update a custom website without them having to touch the code?

Tags: html, web-development, css, html-editor, wysiwyg

I am looking for some way to allow updating of this website: [StrathRowing](https://dandyrow.github.io/StrathRowing)  without people needing to touch the html and css.

Preferebly something that can be hosted on [one.com](https://www.one.com) as that is the current hosting provider for the old website and something that is free.

Ideally I am looking for a wysiwyg editor that can edit my html and css.

Requirements:

- Text editing
- Ability to change images
- automatic nav update
- code editing
- wysiwyg editor

Comment: You want a Content Management System (CMS)

Comment: Will that allow me to change most of the content on the webpages?

Comment: Really depends on the feature set that you want - which would make a good question here.  For example, do you want template pages? Only allow editing text in a specific area or part of the template?  Do you want to allow them to paste in HTML formatted code, or include javascript or other dynamic programming language code?  Do you need permission control for various sub-pages? Automatic navigation updates?

Comment: Hmm, text editing, the ability to change the images. Automatic nav update would be good if possible. Editing code is probably an important feature in case something needs changed in the code

Comment: so.. . I'd think up a good question, then either delete this one and re-post or edit this one with the new content....

Comment: hundreds of wiki's exist compare some of them on https://www.wikimatrix.org/   However, wether or not they can be intergrated into one.com is a whole different question.